# How to arrange field name and the fielt itself properly?

Tags: forms, input

Code:

```
 #inputfield {
 width:300px;
 border: 2px solid #3f3f3f;
 height:30px;
 font-size:20px;
 padding-left:5px;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 }
 #inputname {
 margin-right:10px;
 font-size:20px;
 color: #3f3f3f;
 }


 <a id="inputname>Name:</a><input name="name" id="inputfield" type="text">
 <a id="inputname>Other Name:</a><input name="other" id="inputfield" type="text">
 <a id="inputname>Other Other Name:</a><input name="other_2" 
 id="inputfield" type="text">
```

The names and the fields look out of place.  I am trying to make the form organized like the way it looks on this page:

```
  https://secure.hulu.com/signup
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one item with the same `id`. You mean `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Things to change:

1. Don't use `id`. Use `class` and `.inputfield`
2. Make sure to set the `display` to `inline-block` so that the browser will honor the `width`
3. You don't want `<a>` tags. You want `<label>` tags.
4. Wrap each line of your form in its own `<div>` and use that to set the line height and spacing.